# Typesafety in Vue3 Store pattern

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, store

I am using the Vue3 Store pattern as described here.
https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#simple-state-management-with-reactivity-api

My store However is a Typescript file, as I would like to add type safety to my store.

I can't really find how to add that...

```
import {reactive} from "vue";

export const ColorService = reactive({
    loading: false,

    toggleLoading(): void {
        this.loading = !this.loading;
    }
});
```

How can I add type safety for `loading` to make sure it is a boolean?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-reactive

Comment: It is already typed (inferred as boolean).